# Inserting html code from XML file using DOM

Tags: html, xml, dom

I'm retrieving some data from a XML file, and there is an element that contains a lot of html code, and when I try to put that code inside a `<p>` tag using innerHTML, it appears as plain text.

Do you know how to put all of the code inside the `<p>` tag and make it act as HTML code? I'm using pure AJAX. No frameworks.

This is my code 

`var xml = xhttp.responseXML;
var item = xml.getElementsByTagName("description")[1].innerHTML; //This retrives the code
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = item;`

Comment: How are you placing the xml into the dom? What language? What framework if any?

Comment: @brianlmerritt I updated my question. Sorry for lack of information

Comment: It would help a lot if you could create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem, for us to work on. It probably should include a portion of the read XML file as well, with a couple of `description` tags.